# How do I get more info about a python error?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a python script on `Ubuntu 16.04`; the script runs fine on `Ubuntu 14.04`, but I keep getting kind of a vague `object has no attribute` error.

It seems this exception class is [still active](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html) so not sure what the problem is. I've installed `python-urllib3` and `python3-urllib3` (even though python on the 16.04 system is a symlink to python-2.7) with no luck.

This is my error and line 507 from the code. Any way to get more info about the error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./jsontest.py", line 507, in <module>
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'error'
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import re
import json
import sys
import getopt
...
# line 507
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
   print "fail: ", e.reason
...
```

**update:** As noted by @a_guest. Had to make this change. Why it runs fine on 14.04 I don't know. Maybe this was the difference bewteen 2.7.6 and 2.7.12:

```
except urllib2.error.URLError as e:
```

Comment: use `traceback`

Comment: @jedwards - Mostly.  14.04 ships with 2.7.6 while 16.04 ships with python 2.7.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You linked the documentation for Python 3 however you seem to be using Python 2. [`urllib` on Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) doesn't have that `error` module, just as the error states.

[`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.URLError) on the other hand has this class, so you can use `urllib2.URLError` instead.

Comment: alternatively, run the script with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the urllib module contains nothing called `error`.
My urllib doesn't have an `error` submodule.

Comment: Maybe specific to python3? `The urllib module has been split into parts and renamed in Python 3 to urllib.request, urllib.parse, and urllib.error` https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Answer (score 0):

Note that Ubuntu 16.04 `/usr/bin/python` is a symlink to `python2`. If you want to use python 3.x, you should  change the first line of your script from

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

(Note: the "#!" at the beginning of this line is called "shebang".)

Alternatively you can create a virtual environment so that when you activate it, it will run python 3.

Comment: Thanks. The symlink to `/usr/bin/python` on 14.04 is also python2 (/usr/bin/python -> python2.7) so pretty sure I'm not trying to run it on python3

Comment: @ServerFault If you change the first line of the file as I suggest in my question, you can run the script with python 3.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind however I've not made the provisions in the script to switch to python3 yet (eg: wrapping print() strings in parenthesis, etc) .